# Oracle: Conditional UPDATE based on SELECT result

Tags: java, oracle, oracle11g, java-8

I would like to perform an update only if the select statement returns a particular value.

Example:

Given table:

```
ItemId | CheckIn
0        0
1        0
2        1
3        1
4        1
```

I would operate a bulk of ItemIds, for example ItemId 1,2,3.

If ALL of the selected ItemIds have CheckIn value 0, then I should Update CheckIn of the ItemIds to 1. Otherwise, if at least one of the selected ItemIds are 1, no update should be performed.

Is this possible in one single SELECT/UPDATE statement at all?!

**Background:**

The check for the CheckIn value and the update which follows must be thread safe (Java 8).

What would work is a seperate SELECT FOR UPDATE before the actual UPDATE statement, which I want to avoid however.

As such, the only other option I think would be to put the SELECT with UPDATE into a single, conditional query, and I'm not sure if that's possible, hence my question.

I'm working with Java 8 btw, so a Java based solution would also be ok if you know a away how to achieve this.

Comment: Why don't you use select statement as a subquery? Something like this: ```update some_table
set some_field = some_value 
where (select some_field = some_value from some_table where some_field in (some_list))```

Comment: I don't need a conditional update in which I update only rows of certain value, I need a conditional update in which I only perform an update if the subquery returns a certain result. As such, I only want to perform an update if NONE of the CheckIn values of the selected ItemIds are of value 1.

Comment: In that case, you might want to store the result from the `select` query in a variable. And then execute the `update` query based on that result.

Comment: That is not thread safe, as described in the original question. And I want to avoid locking the rows, as described

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to do it this way:

**MySQL query:**

```
UPDATE temp_table
SET CheckIn = 1
WHERE ItemId IN (1, 2, 3)
  AND (SELECT sum(derived_table.CheckIn) = 0
       FROM (SELECT CheckIn FROM temp_table WHERE ItemId IN (1, 2, 3)) AS derived_table);
```

**Oracle Query:**

```
UPDATE temp_table
SET CheckIn = 1
WHERE ItemId IN (1, 2, 3)
  AND 0 = (SELECT sum(derived_table.CheckIn)
       FROM (SELECT CheckIn FROM temp_table WHERE ItemId IN (1, 2, 3)) derived_table);
```

I have created a derived table and used a group function `sum()` to handle this scenario. I have tested it out and it's working as described in the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in a merge statement, e.g.:

```
MERGE INTO your_table tgt
  USING (SELECT itemid,
                checkin,
                overall_checkin
         FROM   (SELECT itemid,
                        checkin,
                        MAX(CASE WHEN checkin = 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1) OVER () overall_checkin
                 FROM   your_table
                 WHERE  itemid IN (1, 2, 3))
         WHERE  overall_checkin = 0) src
   ON (tgt.itemid = src.itemid) -- assuming that itemid is a primary/unique column
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE tgt.checkin = 1;
```

And [here is a db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=5fc7cfdc2bf721ffeaeda898a636a42e) demonstrating the merge statement.

Comment: Why make an assumptions if you can merge on rowid?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
UPDATE YOUR_TABLE TOUT
SET
    TOUT.CHECKIN = (
        SELECT
            CASE
                WHEN SUM(T.CHECKIN) = 0 THEN 1
                ELSE TOUT.CHECKIN
            END
        FROM
            YOUR_TABLE T
        WHERE
            T.ITEMID IN (
                1,
                2,
                3
            )
    )
WHERE
    TOUT.ITEMID IN (
        1,
        2,
        3
    );
```

Cheers!!

Comment: This query is worse than the version with `sum()` in `where clause` because it may generate much more undo. Updating a value to itself is not the same as not updating value at all.

Comment: In WHERE clause there is only 3 items. I dont think it will generate much undo data.

Comment: Right, in this case it will not (unless query is executed, say, 1 000 000 times) but it's never a good practice irrespective of number of items. Also, if there will be a new requirement to remove filter by item then your query must be completely refactored.

Comment: Offcourse, you are correct but in this case i dont think we should even think about undo